# swing offscreen rendering with simulated input

Tags: java, swing, scala, opengl

I am trying to do render a swing UI into an OpenGl texture. All that works so far is this piece of code (btw it is Scala, but it should be obvious)

```
var image = new BufferedImage( width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR)
mainFrame.paint(image.getGraphics)
var outputfile = new File("saved.png")
ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile)
```

But those things are still missisg:

- I need to be notified when anything in the swing components changes, so that I can update the glTextures when needed.
- The rendering to a swing window should be disabled
- A virtual mouse would be nice, so that I can use my projected mouse position on the texture
- Dynamic keyboard processing, so that I can activate keyboard processing as long as the UI is active. Else I would use LWJGL input processing.

I think the best way to approach the first two issues would be a Decorator to the Graphics object used to draw all the swing components, but I did not find any way to implant my variation of that class into Swing.

I hope that's it. But if you know a library that has already solved my problem you are welcome, but please do not recommend TWL.